# Wondering why my answer was deleted as the best answer does not work

Tags: support, deleted-answers, specific-answer, undelete-request

I had decided to answer a question due to eventually cracking the issue that the questioner raised. The highest voted answer (1) had been answered that would work in a general case but not this specific case. I tried a few ways and homed in on the correct answer and thought I would share this on StackOverflow. I posted my results and within a couple of hours it was deleted. There was no reason why the moderator deleted it, and no way to ask why he'd done it.

Real shame as this question will affect a lot of systems when Penetration Testers want these changes made and the answers are wrong or unhelpful. Even if the moderator did not agree to the answer others may find it useful.

[Link to question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312125/reject-get-method-on-j-security-check)

Comment: Agreed, can't see why it was deleted and it should be undeleted.

Comment: @Oded can't tell as it's out of my expertise but if the answer was deleted just because the question is bad it's... wrong. The question itself should be closed/deleted in such case.

Comment: By "best" answer do you mean "accepted" answer?

Comment: The highest one.

Comment: @Newt: "The highest one" what? Most votes? At the top of whatever your sort happens to be? Most affected by narcotics? The one with the _big checkmark_? What?

Comment: The highest votes which is the default sort. (Edited question if that helps)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It was deleted in response to a flag indicating that it was not an answer. I don't see how that couldn't have been an answer, so I restored it. Note that we avoid judging the technical merits of an answer for moderation purposes, but in this case your answer appears to be relevant to the question to a certain degree, so I think it's acceptable.

> There was no reason why the moderator deleted it, and no way to ask why he'd done it.

I'm not sure if new users are able to flag their own posts without having the reputation required to do so (normally you would need 15 rep). That being said, you can always post on meta, as you've just done, if flagging is not an option. I'm not the moderator who deleted your answer, but the one who did may answer if he sees this question.

Comment: I believe that the "me too" tone to the start of the answer and the 4 "these don't work" options contributed to the problem.

Comment: Appreciate your quick responses and will take into account your comments on my answering technique next time.

Comment: @Newt It was likely deleted because the first paragraph and the first three bullet points all follow the "I'm having the same problem, and I tried these things and they didn't work" until you get to the last bullet point which is an actual solution. He might not have noticed there *was* an actual solution at the end. I don't really see why those need to be a part of your answer, and making people read through three other bullet points before they get to a real solution doesn't make for a very good answer. It makes for some irritated visitors that just want the solution.

Comment: I realise that but wanted to show why these other potential ones were not worth pursuing, as I had done. I will be more concise.

Comment: @Newt notice that you can edit your answer after it has been posted (unlike typical forums and similar places), so you can still improve it. I come back to my answers even at the distance of years to make improvements to them if a second (or third) reading tells me that I can be clearer. The purpose of SO is to improve the Internet, and improvement is a process...